Existence of a cycle not using consecutive edges from another cycle
Say one has a cubic bridgeless graph $G$ and a cycle $c$ in $G$. Why does there exist another cycle $c'$ with $E(c)\cap E(c')\neq \emptyset$ such that $c'$ doesn't use two edges which are consecutive in $c$?
If $c$ is peripheral, or more strongly, has leaf "attachment" vertices from a component of $G-E(c)$ that are consecutive along c, then this is easy as we can use the edge between them and a path through the component.
In the general case, I've been trying to use DFS and lollipops without any progress really. I had also tried to consider it by expressing the cycle of interest as a linear combination from some cycle space basis.
Edit
I think this is a proof. The idea is we can add nonconsecutive edges from $c$ to form a spanning tree. We have at most $\lfloor E(c)/2\rfloor$ nonconsecutive edges from $c$. We can take a choice of these and then extend them to a spanning forest using the edges from $G-E(c)$. This is possible as long as $$E-E(c) + (\lfloor E(c)/2\rfloor) \geq V-1$$ This becomes $2(E-V+1)\geq E(c)$ or $2(E-V+1/2)\geq E(c)$ depending if $E(c)$ is even or odd. Say that somehow this isn't satisfied. Then we have $2(E-V+1/2)<E(c)\leq V$ regardless. In either case, we have $2(E-V+1/2)<E(c)\leq V \Longrightarrow 2E<3V$, which is a contradiction as our graph is cubic. Thus, we can always make a spanning tree with $\lfloor E(c)/2\rfloor$ nonconsecutive edges from $c$ and some edges from $G-E(c)$. Denote $T$ as a spanning tree made in this way. Let $A=E(c)\backslash E(T)$ be the edges not added from $c$ to make this tree. Then we have a fundamental cycle basis $B=\{c_e: e\in E(G)\backslash E(t)\}$ associated with $T$. We have a subset $D$ of these basis cycles such that $D = \{c_e\in B: e\not\in A\}$. Then any $b\in D$ shares edges with $c$ but only uses nonconsecutive edges.
Harder Proposition
Can such a $c'$ be found such that $c\Delta c'$ is also a connected cycle? Even if restricted to, say, planar graphs?

I don't quite follow your proof. If you have a cut and a cycle that alternate between cut and non-cut edges, after removing the cut edges, you will not be able to find a spanning tree.
